# Automatically preview Latex in org-mode as soon as I finish typing

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, preview-latex

I'm using org-mode in Spacemacs (0.200.10.x).

To preview Latex when I open a file, I understand that I can either set the variable `org-startup-latex-with-latex-preview` to `t` in my `init.el`, or set the local `#+STARTUP: latexpreview` option.

However, I want org-mode to preview Latex fragment as soon as a finish typing it. Is that possible? If possible, I'd love a solution that's already included in Spacemacs so I can keep my `init.el` clean.

Comment: Would an idle-timer function be what you want here?

Comment: I had the same problem. Here is what i came up with:
https://github.com/guanyilun/org-equation-live-preview

Answer (score 12):

I wrote a plugin that does this. You can install the plugin, then add

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-fragtog-mode)
```

to your config.

The plugin enables latex previews when your cursor leaves the fragment, and disables them again when the cursor enters, for further editing.

https://github.com/io12/org-fragtog

Answer (score 6):

While I do not know how to do it realtime, I know it is possible to do after each save. You can use emacs local variables to do the trick. https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables . 
This will generate all latex fragments whenever you save the file. Just append this to the end each file where you want this.

```
# Local variables:
# after-save-hook: org-preview-latex-fragment
# end:
```

If you would like to apply it to all org mode files you will need to use hooks. See this reference for how to apply a hook in only one mode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138029/how-to-add-a-hook-to-only-run-in-a-particular-mode#6141681. This hook will only be active when you are in org mode.

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 
      (lambda () 
         (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'org-preview-latex-fragment nil 'make-it-local)))
```

**Note** After reading the `org.el` definitions for `org-preview-latex-fragment` it is obsolete past org-mode > 8.3. It looks like you need to toggle the latex fragment display. What the following code does is check if the latex fragments are currently rendered if so toggle twice if not toggle once on save)

```
(defun my/org-render-latex-fragments ()
  (if (org--list-latex-overlays)
      (progn (org-toggle-latex-fragment)
             (org-toggle-latex-fragment))
    (org-toggle-latex-fragment)))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'my/org-render-latex-fragments nil 'make-the-hook-local)))
```

Comment: This is smart! Previewing upon saving is a decent option. Do you know how to add this hook for all `.org` files?

Comment: It looks like the function org--list-latex-overlays has been removed in newer versions of org-mode, so the hook doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @FredrikMeyer Do yo see a way to make it work again?

Comment: @student I did not get toggling to work. Now I use
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
              (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'org-preview-latex-fragment nil 'make-it-local))) to preview after save. And just press backspace to edit.

Comment: Thanks that works. Maybe you should use `org-latex-preview` since `org-preview-latex-fragment` seems to be obsolete. Maybe you could add your solution as an answer for other visitors.